# How to use the curses module to display the colors calculated from the HSL model?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

The code is based on three main components: hue, saturation and lightness. Hue represents the color itself, such as red, green, or blue, and is represented as an angle value between 0 and 360 degrees. Saturation indicates the purity or vividness of the color, and ranges from 0 to 100%. Luminosity controls the brightness of the color, also ranging from 0 to 100%.
The result is:
[image]

But when trying to transcribe the code to the curse module, I get totally different color bands.

[image]
Here is the transcript I tried to make for curses, on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/pSBvz9dx).
The font below is the main script which prints at the expected length.
How to get the same lengths in curses module?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct {
  int r;
  int g;
  int b;
} RGB;

RGB newRGB(int r, int g, int b) {
  RGB color;
  color.r = r;
  color.g = g;
  color.b = b;
  return color;
}

void calcColor(RGB* colors, int totalColors, int currentIndex, float saturation, float lightness);

int main() {
  int totalColors = 60;
  RGB colors[totalColors];
  float saturation = 1.0;
  float lightness = 0.3;

  int end = totalColors - 18; // Define the final index of the last desired colors
  int start = end - 42;

  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    calcColor(&colors[i], totalColors, i, saturation, lightness);
  }

  // Print the colors in a block
  for (int i = end; i >= start; i--) {
    printf("\033[48;2;%d;%d;%dm  \033[0m", colors[i].r, colors[i].g, colors[i].b);
  }

  return 0;
}

void calcColor(RGB* colors, int totalColors, int currentIndex, float saturation, float lightness) {
  float hue = currentIndex * (360.0 / totalColors);
  float chroma = (1 - fabs(2 * lightness - 1)) * saturation;
  float x = chroma * (1 - fabs(fmod(hue / 60, 2) - 1));
  float m = lightness - chroma / 2;

  float r, g, b;
  if (hue >= 0 && hue < 60) {
    r = chroma;
    g = x;
    b = 0;
  } else if (hue >= 60 && hue < 120) {
    r = x;
    g = chroma;
    b = 0;
  } else if (hue >= 120 && hue < 180) {
    r = 0;
    g = chroma;
    b = x;
  } else if (hue >= 180 && hue < 240) {
    r = 0;
    g = x;
    b = chroma;
  } else if (hue >= 240 && hue < 300) {
    r = x;
    g = 0;
    b = chroma;
  } else {
    r = chroma;
    g = 0;
    b = x;
  }

  colors->r = (r + m) * 255;
  colors->g = (g + m) * 255;
  colors->b = (b + m) * 255;
}
```

Comment: You should add the actual code in question into the body of your question instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that your code is setting color pairs `i+16`, using color `i` and then turning on color pair `i`:

```
for (int i = end; i >= start; i--) {
    calcColor(&colors[i], totalColors, i, saturation, lightness);
 
    // Convert RGB colors to curses default model
    int r = colors[i].r * 1000 / 255;
    int g = colors[i].g * 1000 / 255;
    int b = colors[i].b * 1000 / 255;
 
    // Set color in curses
    init_color(i + 16, r, g, b);  // need to set color pair i+16
    init_pair(i + 16, COLOR_BLACK, i + 16);
 
   // Print the color
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));  // need to activate color pair i+16
    printw("  ");
    attroff(COLOR_PAIR(i + 16));
}
```

The problem with the funny color bands is almost certainly due to your terminal emulator not supporting changing colors. [See my comment under an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76656552/how-to-make-a-color-gradient-using-rgb-coordinates#comment135151782_76656904). Try a different terminal emulator. This works in [Xfce Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce#Xfce_Terminal) for me.

[image]

Comment: The emulator or the curses it doesn't support? Because when doing it in the purest C it was possible. I had to transcribe it into curses, to encompass a character that moves in the circle.
I wouldn't be using curses if that character didn't fill the screen upwards with blank lines to keep it fixed in one position on the screen.
Is there any other module possible to do this? I'm thinking about term.h, the fuck is that the script is huge.

Comment: What is "the purest C" solution? If you mean the ANSI escape code solution, this is not a feature of C, but must also be supported by terminal emulators. Some emulators have hard-coded color palettes, and ncurses requires changing palettes to access custom colors. Don't know about "other modules", but why not just install a better terminal emulator?

Comment: ok, I'm installing Xfce. Can you show a printout of running the color spectrum?
term.h is not a standard C library and is not part of the pure library suite like stdlib stdio, ..., math

Comment: @Cmistry -- Added an image of the resulting color spectrum.